# Meteor Email pdf attachment with mailgun

Tags: pdf, meteor, email-attachments, mailgun

I can create the pdf file, view in Acrobat locally, send it via email using Email package from Meteor, receive the attachment but it is corrupt. Acrobat can't open it and actually says that the "file is damaged" and suggests that email atachment decoding could be the problem.

I tried "application/octet-stream" with no luck. Any ideas?

```
Email.send({
               to: "bhattacharya.sudi@gmail.com",
               from: from,
               subject: fn.alertTypeLabel + ' ' + p[0].parameterLabel,
               html: SSR.render( template, templateDataContext ),
               attachments : [ { fileName : fileName, filePath : filesPath, contentType : contentType } ]
                            });
```

Attachment contentType is set to `"application/pdf"`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What could help is to pass in the 'contents' parameter as part of your attachment.

In my own project I do this as such:

```
var fs = Meteor.npmRequire('fs');
var myPath = "assets/app/test.pdf"; // this should be wherever you store your pdf
fs.readFile(myPath, function (err, data) {
    if (err) {
        throw err;
    }

    Email.send({
        from: test@gmail.com,
        to: otherTest@gmail.com,
        subject: 'mySubject',
        attachments: [{'filename': 'myFileName 'contents': data}],
        html:  SSR.render( template, templateDataContext ),
    });
}
```

I read the file test.pdf and return its data using 'fs.readFile', which I insert into my list of email parameters.

Comment: Hi Joos: Your solution worked great. Thank you. I am using a third party tool to save the pdf. So in the callback of the third party (after the file is saved successfully) I am calling readFile and in the callback of readFile I am sending the email. I had to wrap the callbacks in Meteor.bindEnvironment for them to work.